# 750 will not idle or run without choke fully on

Tags: honda, motorcycle, cb750

1977 Honda 750 will only run with choke fully on, it will only idle at 3000rpm, idle setting does nothing.  Carbs are clean and rebuilt. It will rev up but appears to be burning quite lean.

Comment: Re-check the idle jet - it sounds blocked.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While you state carbs are clean and rebuilt, this is where the problem lies. Figure out what's going on with your carbs and you'll fix your issue. Check to ensure floats and jets are set correctly.

Comment: pull up your tank and verify that you haven't pinched the fuel line. look closely...